# How to pass a 2D ArrayList to a 1D ArrayList

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am trying to use XML to save user inputs. My issue is that when I reopen the original XML file gets overwritten rather than having the new `<savedPosition>` added to the file. I have a 2D array that stores the `<savedPositions>` already in the XML file. What I want to do is pass the already stored positions to a new array so that no data is lost. The issue is my array stores the past positions in a 2D arraylist and the new positions are stored in a 1D arraylist. How do I add the 2D array to the 1D array list?

My 2D arraylist is:

```
 List<ArrayList<String>> obj = XmlToObject.main(loadProjectUrl);
```

My ArrayList is:

```
ArrayList<SavedPosition> posList = new ArrayList<SavedPosition>();
```

My code:
Save Position code:

```
//SAVE SAVED POSITION
    save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String SAVEDPOS_XML = get.getLoadProjectUrl();

        String a = mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().mrl();
        String b = mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().mrl();

        SavedPosition saved = new SavedPosition();
        saved.setPosition1(mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().getTime());
        saved.setPosition2(mediaPlayerComponent2.getMediaPlayer().getTime());
        saved.setNBehaviour(textArea.getText());
        saved.setABehaviour(textArea1.getText());
        saved.setGap(textArea2.getText());
        saved.setForces(textArea3.getText());
        saved.setFindings(textArea2.getText());
        saved.setVideo1Url(a);
        saved.setVideo2Url(b);
        posList.add(saved);

        SavedPositions savedPos = new SavedPositions();
        savedPos.setSavedPositions(posList);

            try {

                //create JAXB context and instantiate marshaller
                JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(SavedPositions.class);
                Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
                m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

                //print
                //m.marshal(savedPos, System.out);
                //write to file
                m.marshal(savedPos, new File(SAVEDPOS_XML));

            } catch (JAXBException ex) {
                System.out.println( ex);
            }
        }
    });
```

Code to read XML file:
    public class XmlToObject {

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> main(String url) {

ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> obj1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> obj = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

try{
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document d = db.parse(url);
    XPath xp = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    NodeList nl = (NodeList) xp.compile("//savedPosition").evaluate(d, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    System.out.println("number of saved positions " + nl.getLength());

    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++){

        String a = (xp.compile("./NBehaviour").evaluate(nl.item(i)));
        String b = (xp.compile("./ABehaviour").evaluate(nl.item(i)));
        String c = (xp.compile("./gap").evaluate(nl.item(i)));
        String d1 = (xp.compile("./forces").evaluate(nl.item(i)));
        String e = (xp.compile("./findings").evaluate(nl.item(i)));
        String f = (xp.compile("./position1").evaluate(nl.item(i)));
        String g = (xp.compile("./position2").evaluate(nl.item(i)));
        String h = (xp.compile("./video1Url").evaluate(nl.item(i)));
        String ii = (xp.compile("./video2Url").evaluate(nl.item(i)));

        ArrayList<String> savedPosition = new ArrayList<String>();

        savedPosition.add(a);
        savedPosition.add(b);
        savedPosition.add(c);
        savedPosition.add(d1);
        savedPosition.add(e);
        savedPosition.add(f);
        savedPosition.add(g);
        savedPosition.add(h);
        savedPosition.add(ii);

        obj.add(savedPosition);

    }

    return obj;

}catch(Exception l){
    System.out.println(l.getMessage());
    //String message = "No Project Found - Please load or create one";
    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), message);
}

    return obj1;
}
}
```

Comment: Did you debug your code? Where are you trying to add the content of `obj` to `posList`? Why doesn't `XmlToObject.main()` (I'd change that method name btw) return a `List<SavedPosition>` instead of a 2d string list?

Comment: Both my arrays cotain the correct data, I'm just not sure on how to pass it to the other array so that my data is not overwritten. My code works when a new file is created and used, the issue comes when opening a project which already has data - as it gets overwritten instead of being added to. I need it to be 2D so that the array can contains the information for each saved position, e.g. their is a savedPosition1, savedPosition2. My question is more how would I go about not loosing the previous saved data when opening a previous project?

Comment: "how would I go about not loosing the previous saved data when opening a previous project?" - Without knowing your XML structure etc. it's hard to go into details (and I'd leave those for you anyways) but basically what you can do is this: load the existing file and unmarshal it, make the needed changes (add/edit/remove positions), marshal the data back to the XML file. Currently you are creating a new file and thus overwrite any existing data - just don't do that.

Comment: Do you know of any good tutorials? I've unmarshalled the file now but I don't know how to append to it. Thanks